# Изменение класса div-a при переключении слайда в slick слайдере

Tags: html, css, jquery, slider, slick.js

Нужно написать простой скрипт jQuery, при котором после измениния слайда на другой, который имеет параметры активного на данный момент (aria-hidden и tabindex) и параметр конкретного слайда (data-skick-index), добавлялся (addClass) класс в другом блоке HTML документа. Так же, что бы он снимался (removeClass), когда меняется data-skick-index на другой. Спасибо за ответы. [image: скрин]

Answer (score 0):

Подсказали на хабре. Возможно кому то пригодится.

```js
$('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide){
    if (currentSlide == 1) {
    $('.anotherClass').addClass('addedClass');
    }else {
     $('.anotherClass').removeClass('addedClass');
    };
 });
```